# Certain websites do not open. Instead a 1*1 image gets displayed

Tags: internet

When I try to visit certain websites like www.bidvertiser.com, www.buysellads.com, a white page shows up, the title bar displays the site name followed by (1x1) in brackets. When I right click, 'View Source' option appears disabled. The Save As.. option shows the file type to be gif. However, when I preview the site in Google search results ( by moving the mouse over >> ) the screenshot of the site displays well. This happens on all the three browsers on my computer: Chrome, Firefox and IE. What is the problem and how can it be resolved? 
EDIT: At some point of time, they probably worked on my computer! I think it is a more general problem. The same happens when I click on certain links in Google search results.

Comment: Interesting. The sites work fine on my computer.

Comment: could be rogue dns that redirects your requests, firewalls could also do this. Try opening this direct link to _www.bidvertiser.com_ [http://216.200.199.56](http://216.200.199.56) to skip dns. There's however other possibilities too...

Comment: Has someone installed Privoxy on the computer? It's a proxy server that can block various things and certain blocked items are represented by 1x1 gifs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer. It is Kaspersky's AntiBanner feature causing the problem. After I have disabled it, the sites are opening fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you're using AdBlock. I used to have the same issue until I found out it was somehow caused by AdBlock.

Comment: OP has the same problem with three browsers including Internet Explorer. I don't think Adblock Plus is available for Internet Explorer. I don't know which "AdBlock" you're referring to.

Answer (score -1):

*Update
If using Avast! disable browser integration(Settings->Browser Integration) and web shield(Only if browser integration doesn't fix it) to fix this issue. Not Ideal but it works